# Submit form with multiple input with the same name with comma delimitted text

Tags: java, forms

I have a form with many same name input. I catch the value in Controller and split them by `comma [,]` to make `String[]` array. Form like below.

[image]

Getting text as `java.lang.String` as `"Sugar,Potato"` and `"45,20"` then I split these text to `Array` like `String particulars = "Sugar,Potato";` and `String prices = "45,20";`

`String[] particularArr = particulars.split(",");` and

`String[] priceArr = prices.split(",");`.

But the problem comes when I submit particular text contains `comma` like the picture below...

[image]

The particular text comes as `String particulars = "Breakfast, Lunch,Pen, Paper";` and when I `split()` this text this returns 4 sized `Array` for four `comma` how can I solve this problem ?

Additional note... I am using `@RequestParam String particulars` at `Spring` controller to catch the form value.

Code sample:

```
<form action="/someAction.go" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="particulars" value="Breakfast, Lunch"/>
    <input type="text" name="particulars" value="Pen, Paper"/>

    <input type="text" name="prices" value="45">
    <input type="text" name="prices" value="120">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I submit the form, the `@RequestParam` shows valuses as..

`String particulars = "Breakfast, Lunch,Pen, Paper"`.

How can I get two input value separately in Spring controller ?

Comment: You should consider using a delimiter that is not an allowable character for your Particular/note edit field.

Comment: can you provide a code sample? It seems to me you have to provide different value in the option for those option.In general <option name="a" value="pen">Pen,Paper</option> should be used.but without seeing code its hard to tell.

Comment: I usually use `|` as a delimiter, but you can some other Character or Characters e.g. `''&%$#'` as a delimiter if you want

Comment: @ScaryWombat User can use any Delimiter in input text.

Comment: You could also use some unicode that the user is very very unlikely to use

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have doubt, where to use unicode. the inputs with the same name submits the values by joining itself by comma delimiter. How can I change this comma ?

Comment: @RawAliasCoder Edited post with code sample for you please.